# How to get updated vertex coordinates as object moves

Tags: game-engine

```
mesh = obj.meshes[0]

for index in range(mesh.numPolygons):  # iterate over faces
    polygon = mesh.getPolygon(index)
    polyMesh = polygon.getMesh()
    mat_index = polygon.getMaterialIndex()
    for poly_vert_index in range(polygon.getNumVertex()):
        mesh_vert_index = polygon.getVertexIndex(poly_vert_index)
        vertex = mesh.getVertex(mat_index, mesh_vert_index)
        print("Index ",index," polyIndex ",poly_vert_index," vertex ",mesh_vert_index," coord ",vertex.x)
```

As i move the object (by applying force) the coordinates of each vertex remain the same, how do i get the updated coordinates as the object moves and rotates. Also how do i get the updated face normals of the moving object?

Comment: Visit this link and look at the part on geting global position of a vertex http://q-tutsblog.rf.gd/how-to-create-laser-beam-reflection-in-blender-game-engine/

Answer (score 2):

Reading the mesh provides you with vertex data relative to the object the mesh belongs to = coordinates in Object Space.

As long as you do not deform the mesh this data will remain unchanged.

According to your question you want to get the data in *Scene Space*. This means it will change when you move or turn the object or one of it's parents.

## Positional vectors

You can convert positional vectors from object space to scene space by multiplying them with the object transformation matrix:

```
positionInSceneSpace = owner.worldTransform * vertex.XYZ
```

## Normal vector

The normal Vector is not a positional vector. It's purpose is to represent a direction rather than a position. Therefore you consider rotation transformation only:

```
normalInSceneSpace = owner.worldOrientation * vertex.normal
```

Comment: UV.. probably me.. but I've not come across the term 'Scene Space' used in Blender before, as opposed to 'World Space' (..isn't that shared by all scenes?) I could be wrong.. or just pedantic ... ;)